# Change input source shorcut for mac os el capitan

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-elcapitan

To change the input source I must press ctrl and space. Is there a way to turn back to the command/space combination?

Answer (score 6):

I was having trouble changing this option also. Here is what worked for me:

1) Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts

2) Click on Spotlight on the left side to show the Spotlight shortcuts. Command+space is the default shortcut for opening the Spotlight search window.

3) Deselect the checkbox for 'Show Spotlight search' (and 'Show Finder search window, if you like).

4) Then click the 'Input Sources' shortcuts on the left.

5) Select the 'Select the previous input source' shortcut *by tapping on the actual key combination* on the far right side - there is a less than obvious text field there that can be modified. Tap again if necessary to highlight this text field.

6) With the text field highlighted, tap the key combination you want to use, such as Command+space.

7) Close the preferences and your new key combination should work!

This is not clearly explained in Apple's documentation on the feature.

Comment: Can this be done without hitting Space? I want to change it to CTRL+Shift because I do that on Windows but without a Space or Return at the end it's not changing

Comment: I am interested in the same question - is it possible to not use Space? Just Shift+Control for example?

Comment: Can I do it through terminal?

Answer (score 5):

Sure there is.
Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Input sources. There, select the "Select previous input source" option, click on its current shortcut (i.e. ^Space) and press the key combination you want to use.